# TypeError 'int' not callable but I'm passing a string to my decrypt function in python

Tags: python, encryption

I'm working on a function that is passed a encrypted string, then returns the decoded string.  The error message is TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.  How do I tell python the argument is a string? ...or what am I telling python to make it think I'm passing an 'int'?

Thanks!

this is from pythonchallenge.com[1]

the decrpytion is each letter is written as 2 letters previous.

'ams' = 'you'

```
def decrypt(msg):
    ord = 0
    decoded = ""
    for letter in msg:
        #any number from 97 to 121 will have no rem. They don't warp around.
        #121 & 122 will have rem 1 & 2, so they need +=97 
        ord = (ord(letter) + 2)%123
        if ord < 97:
            ord += 97
        decoded += ord
    return decoded
```

Comment: Don't declare variables that uses the same names as builtins...

Comment: As @JeffMercado writes, but to give it a technical term for those not familiar yet, when you use the same var name in a tighter scope, the tighter scope var *shadows* the outer scope usage. Usually unnecessary and certainly more complex. So *don't* shadow builtins if you don't need to.

Comment: @shawn I def didn't need to shadow it. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
def decrypt(msg):
    ord = 0
```

The red light is going off. [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) is the name of a python function. You would never want to use the name of a function as a variable name. You lose access to that function, and can't use it later on. Rename it to `value` or something. Call `1('hello there!')` is not going to work: How can I make `1` a function?

Comment: thanks! I changed var ord to ascii...it worked once I added "decoded += chr(ascii)"

Answer (score 2):

You define `ord = 0` locally in line 2, overriding function `ord`. Consider a different name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
ord(letter)
```

ord is an integer so you can't do ord(letter)

Comment: Nope... that's not it. Look closer.

Comment: that actually is it .... ord == 0 .... ergo ord is indeed an integer ... (in this case)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Actually, that's not the issue. That code will work fine in Python. The issue is that `ord` is now a variable, and no longer a function. This doesn't explain why it fails, nor does it even point to what the author is doing wrong.

Comment: it does explain why it fails ... it does not point out what the author is doing wrong ...

Comment: I will try to put more informative answers.  However, if ord is set to and int, and then I do "ord(x)", doesn't this try to call a function on an integer?  Regardless if ord is a builtin or not...